# How do I pass variable value as parameter to format function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to create a `format` logic where I need to pass a parameter to the `format` function from a variable rather that coding it.

```
 key = "test"
 inpText = "replace {test} with value"
 inpText = inpText.format(key = "done")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a function with f-strings for that?

```
def fill_input(key):
    return f"replace {key} with value"

>>> print(fill_input("test"))
"replace test with value"
>>> print(fill_input("done"))
"replace done with value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `key` will be looked for as a placeholder. While it doesn't raise an error to provide extra placeholders to `format`, the `test` placeholder will be missing. To pass the string inside `key` as a placeholder, you can use **keyword** unpacking using a dict:

```py
key = "test"
inpText = "replace {test} with value"

replacements = {key: "done"}
inpText = inpText.format(**replacements)
print(inpText)
```

will print:

```
replace done with value
```